# Does a beaker filled with water weigh more with an object in it?

Tags: fluid-statics

Assuming that I have a beaker of water kept on a weighing machine.
If I put an object on the surface of the water, will the reading on the weighing machine increase? 
I think yes, because the body exerts pressure on the liquid and it will be transmitted according to Pascal's law.

Am I right?
Also will the answer depend on the fact whether the object is partially immersed/fully immersed/sunk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, the question is posed with the addition, that the beaker is full before.

In this case, some water will pour over. Then your second question makes sense: if the object is lighter that water and floats, the mass of the poured water will be equal to the mass of the object and the weight will remain the same. Whereas if the body sinks, then it will exert some additional pressure on the ground (which is not compensated by the spilling of water), and the weight will increase.

Comment: what if I have a  tall beaker which has been filled to half its capacity?Water won;t overflow this time.So will it weigh more?

Comment: Yes, of course; the weights simply add up, why shouldn't they!?

Answer (score 1):

Yep, the reading will increase whether the object sinks or floats.

Comment: can you please elaborate?Why is it so?

Comment: The water exerts a upwards (buoyant) force on the object - the object exerts an equal and opposite downwards force on the water so the weighing machine must exert a larger force up on the water.

Comment: @KaranSingh Singh:   Have you drawn a free body diagram for the combination of beaker, water, and object?  This is why we learn to draw free body diagrams.  Do you feel that you have advanced beyond the point where you need to use free body diagrams?

Comment: I did.I somehow had it in my mind that since the body is kept at the top of the water surface,the weight won't show up on the scale.

Comment: The free body diagram should have conclusively settled that doubt.